# How To Edit The Font Of A Testimonial Carousel in Squarespace Using CSS?

Tags: css, squarespace

I am trying to edit the font of some text within a testimonial preset carousel within Squarespace (on the home page of the site linked below).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZUwR.png)

I have successfully changed the text below it using the following code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ja83.png)

```
section[data-section-id="63c390bd1403971a5efb5e19"]
  
  
    .user-items-list-item-container p
   {
  font-family: "Steelfish";
  font-size: 31px;
}
```

However I cannot seem to find a way to change the font of this main text.

I am open to all suggestions and am getting quite desperate as this job has carried on a lot longer than anticipated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

https://orb-seahorse-ha47.squarespace.com/

password123

```
/* attempt at testimonials top text */
section[data-section-id="63c390bd1403971a5efb5e19"]


    .user-items-list-carouselslides user-items-list-carouselslides--initialized p
   {
  font-family: "Steelfish";
  font-size: 31px;
}
Tried this unsuccessfully
Also tried h, h1, h2, h3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless we do a lot of digging, it looks like the font-size is going to need the dreaded !important.  See if this will work for you:

```
section[data-section-id="63c390bd1403971a5efb5e19"] h2.list-item-content__title {
 font-family: "Steelfish";
 font-size: 51px!important;
 }
```